# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 merge data of exactly two adjacent rows into one row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

current state of #master table:

[image: current state of table]

I've been trying to formulate a SELECT query to achieve following by picking Value column of exactly two adjecent rows and then placing it on a single row in two columns.

[image: intended output]

My solution so far:

clone the master table.

1. Select first row Value from master table.
2. Then join master table with the clone on Id and pick the value from +1 incremented id...
3. Skip the next Id from master
4. repeat step 1-3 till end of master table

   ````
    select *
   into #clone
   from #master


   Select Value AS Value1 from #master
          Value AS Value2 from #clone  
   inner join #clone
     ON #master.Id /*(incremented id)*/ = #clone.Id /*(incremented id)*/
   -- skip the next id of #master```
   ````

stuck on increment and skipping the next id part of #master table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating the table and inserting some values

```
create table mastertable
(
id int,
Name varchar(20),
ParentID int,
Value varchar(50)
)

insert into mastertable values(86, 'Description1',83,'021541-sds2-45515')
insert into mastertable values(87, 'value1',83, '$247.56')
insert into mastertable values(90, 'Description3',83, '021541-sds2-45567')
insert into mastertable values(91,'value3',83, '$66.72')
insert into mastertable values(94, 'Description5',83, '021541-sd72-47715')
insert into mastertable values(95,'value5',83, '$57.11')
```

Now, try this query:

```
with m1 as
(
SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by id) FROM mastertable
),
m2 as
(
SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by id) FROM mastertable
)

SELECT m1.id, m1.name, m1.parentid, m1.value as value1, m2.value as value2
FROM  m1 left join  m2
ON m1.RN = m2.RN-1
WHERE  m1.RN%2 != 0
```

EDIT:
For m2, instead of SELECT *, you could also use:

```
m2 as
(
SELECT id,value, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by id) FROM mastertable
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Viraj ... that helped me in solving the problem...

Comment: After some experimentation i learnt that this error could be possible if these statements are  used along with other statements. "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, 
an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon." so to avoid this it is guided to always use "with" as ";with"... might be helpful for someone else...